# Fortran FORMAT Expected INTEGER for item 5 in formatted transfer, got REAL

Tags: fortran, format, syntax-error

I am trying to read in the following input data file using the piece of code I have shown below. I, however, am getting an error. I've reviewed the code several times but can't seem to find what the problem is as I believe format specification for reading line 2 in is alright.

ERROR:

```
Fortran runtime error: Expected INTEGER for item 5 in formatted transfer, got REAL 
(a3,2(4x,i2,i3,i4),4x,f6.1,f4.1,f7.2,f5.2,f8.
         ^
```

INPUT FILE (4 lines):

```
C022980A 02/29/80 11:13:26.7   6.30  126.88 104.06.10.0PHILIPPINE ISLANDS      
MLI BW:12 36  45 MW: 7 14 135 DT=   3.9 0.2   6.13 0.02  127.17 0.02  79.3  1.6
DUR 4.0 EX 25  3.01 0.07 -0.78 0.06 -2.23 0.06  1.52 0.07  2.14 0.07  1.00 0.07  
4.38 62 314  -1.29 22 173  -3.09 16  77   3.74 138 35   49   5 64  115
```

CODE:

```
      inut = 1
      OPEN(inut,file=cevent,iostat=ios,status='old',err=999)
      read(inut,1001)code,month,day,year,hour,min,sec,lat,lon,depth,
     1            mb,ms,region
 1001 format(a8,5(1x,a2),1x,f4.1,f7.2,f8.2,f6.1,2f3.1,a24)     
      read(inut,1002)epsrc,bwst,bwrec,bwcoff,mwst,mwrec,mwcoff,
     1            dt,edt,clat,eclat,clon,eclon,cdepth,ecdepth
 1002 format(a3,2(4x,i2,i3,i4),4x,f6.1,f4.1,
     1       f7.2,f5.2,f8.2,f5.2,f6.1,f5.1)
      read(inut,1003)ahdur,expo,rmom(1),emrr,rmom(2),emss,rmom(3),emee,
     1            rmom(4),emrs,rmom(5),emre,rmom(6),emse
 1003 format(4x,f4.1,4x,i2,6(f6.2,f5.2))
      read(inut,1004)ev(1),evpl(1),evaz(1),ev(2),evpl(2),evaz(2),
     2              ev(3),evpl(3),evaz(3),smo,strike(1),dip(1),rake(1),
     4              strike(2),dip(2),rake(2)
 1004 format(3(f7.2,i3,i4),f7.2,2(i4,i3,i5))
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is the best I could do with this piece of already existing code an input. I have to retain the format statements, without which the calculation could be affected elsewhere in the code in case I make a mistake.

Comment: Was the "unquoted slashes" directed at me? If so, I didn't get you?

Comment: Is `mwst` declared real?

Comment: Oh! Thank you! That was indeed the problem.